How to set keybindings.json for navigating explorer in VS Code?
I really tried, but after dozens of tutorials, hours of googling and endless GPT queries, I gave up. I have nowhere else to go.
Essentially, what I want to achieve is to have VS Code explorer pane under cmd+1 shortcut.
To be more precise, how I want the keybinding to work is this:

If the explorer is not visible and you're either inside a file or outside, then on cmd+1, it becomes visible and in focus. Then when you click cmd+1 again, it disappears.

However, if you moved on to editing the file and the explorer is open and not in focus, then cmd+1 will make it in focus again. It's basically how it works in JetBrains IDEs.


I'd really appreciate help in solving this issue as it's driving me crazy.
This is one of the things I tried but it didn't work in the end.
[
    {
        "key": "cmd+1",
        "command": "workbench.view.explorer",
        "when": "!sideBarVisible"
    },
    {
        "key": "cmd+1",
        "command": "workbench.action.focusSideBar",
        "when": "sideBarVisible && !sideBarFocus"
    },
    {
        "key": "cmd+1",
        "command": "workbench.action.closeSidebar",
        "when": "sideBarVisible && sideBarFocus"
    }
]

